# DynamicData - Unable to move the static method to another class (Even Base class)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I'm developing a Dynamic Data Test (c#) as described in https://www.meziantou.net/mstest-v2-data-tests.htm#using-dynamicdata.

By keeping both the Dynamic Data Test and the static method within the same class, then all works fine, but when trying to move the static class to another class (Even Base class), then the test doesn't run and I get an error message:

Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: Method GetData

Can you please assist?

When moving the method to another class, I tried to make it as none-static too, but that didn't help.

```
[TestClass]
public class MathTests
{
    [DataTestMethod]
    [DynamicData(nameof(GetData), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
    public void Test_Add_DynamicData_Method(int a, int b, int expected)
    {
        var actual = MathHelper.Add(a, b);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetData()
    {
        yield return new object[] { 1, 1, 2 };
        yield return new object[] { 12, 30, 42 };
        yield return new object[] { 14, 1, 15 };
    }
}
```

Comment: "*trying to move the static class*" There is no static class here. Do you perhaps mean, "*trying to move the static **method***"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the alternate constructor for the attribute that includes the type that contains the target data source

For example

```
[TestClass]
public class MathTests
{
    [DataTestMethod]
    [DynamicData(nameof(ExternalClass.GetData), typeof(ExternalClass), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
    public void Test_Add_DynamicData_Method(int a, int b, int expected)
    {
        var actual = MathHelper.Add(a, b);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

}

public class ExternalClass
{
    public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetData()
    {
        yield return new object[] { 1, 1, 2 };
        yield return new object[] { 12, 30, 42 };
        yield return new object[] { 14, 1, 15 };
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you - that solves the issue. 
I'm wonder if it is possible to make the DynamicData attribute applicable for all tests without actually add it to each test

Comment: @NadeemBader No. You would need to add it to the tests. the attribute is metadata that the test framework uses to exercise the tests.